# Some CSS styles not working on SVG

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am working on this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/x2pxx92e/6/

I have this code for mouseover and out events :

```
d3.select('#circleSVG').on('mouseover', function(d) {
  console.log('mouseover')

  d3.select(this).classed('testCircle', true)
  console.log(this)
}).on('mouseout', function(){

  d3.select(this).classed('testCircle', false)
})
```

The `testCircle` class looks like so :

```
.testCircle{
  fill: orange;
  opacity:0.25;
}
```

But the only style that gets brought through on this class is the opacity. It doesn't change the fill. Any idea why ?

Comment: @lamelemon legend, been trying to figure it out for a while, thank you

Comment: @lamelemon there is no need to use !important, it's a really bad practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Specificity

The ID has a higher specifity that the class.

Just make the selector more specific. `important` is not recommended.

```
#circleSVG {
  fill: red;
  stroke: green;
}

#circleSVG.testCircle{
  fill: orange;
  opacity:0.25;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s87zjsL1/)

Comment: Can you tell me how come it's not recommended ? In my actual offline code there is no id I can use as there are hundreds of nodes so I just use classes ?

Comment: `Important` should only be used as an absolute last resort. Once applied it's almost impossible to override **again**

Comment: ok thank you, I'll do some more research. I think in my case it should be okay :)

Comment: @thatOneGuy [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) a good answer on the implications of important.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is basically how the CSS selectors works.

Basically an id selector (#) is more specific than a class selector (.). So the "fill: orange" property in the class selector (.testCircle) is not being applied because the id selector (#testCircle) is more specific and also have a fill property. On the other hand, the opacity property is working because the id selector doesn't specify that property.

To fix this you can add "!important" as follow:

```
.testCircle{
  fill: orange !important;
  opacity:0.25;
}
```

Or even better, make your selector more specific:

```
#circleSVG.testCircle{
   fill: orange !important;
   opacity:0.25;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use JS to accomplish that? You can use only css.

```
#circleSVG {
  fill: red;
  stroke: green;
}

#circleSVG:hover {
  fill: orange;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x2pxx92e/11/

Comment: Sorry should have said, my offline version needs a click event not a hover

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to change a class, but you also have an ID to define the svg color, so it's better to change the color of the ID when it's hover:

```
#circleSVG:hover{
  fill: orange;
  opacity:0.25;
}
```

To change the color by the ID, you can use

```
element = document.getElementById(id);
```